# Can I use maraschino cherrys in a dump cake when it calls for cherry pie filling?

Tags: substitutions, cake, crockpot, pineapple, cherries

Can the cherry pie filling be replaced with maraschino cherries in a Crock-Pot cherry pineapple dump cake n is there any thing different with the directions if I use the maraschino cherries?

Comment: Would you share your recipe with us? Based on the ratios (e.g. how much pie filling compared to the rest of the ingredients), it may or may not make a difference.

Comment: What's a dump cake?

Comment: @GdD https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dump_cake

Comment: You should specify if you mean the 'original' maraschino cherries which are soft and made with liqueur, or the more common candied version which are harder and with a very different flavour.

Answer (score 2):

While it's technically possible, you probably won't like the result. Maraschino cherries are a very different flavor and texture from cherry pie filling. Cherry pie filling is soft, gooey and balances sweetness and tartness. Maraschino cherries are hard, candied cherries, and the liquid is very strong.

Comment: The OP might mean the original maraschino cherries which aren't hard or candied in the same way (although much of this answer will apply anyway).

Comment: I'm making an assumption that this is one of those 'what have I got in my larder, and can I use it?' based questions @dbmag9.

Comment: I've got the former in my larder (although I strictly restrict them to cocktails, they're expensive and *extremely* moreish).